# How to prove: if $a$ is an even integer, $\gcd(a^3 - 1, a + 1) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I have very little idea of how to tackle this question. I know if $a$ is even, $a = 2L$, for some $L$ in the integer set.

Comment: Hint:  $a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$ and, since $a$ is odd, $(a+1,a-1)=1$

Comment: but a is even in the problem.
and i knew to use the difference of cubes, but i don't see where that gets me

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "since $a$ is even" in my comment.  But, with that correction:  just note that $(a+1,a^2+a+1)=(a+1,a^2)$.

Comment: The posted solution spells this out (and avoids the blunder I made).

Comment: Lulu thank you so much for your help this evening! I really appreciate it!

Comment: This is all the charm of accepting an answer right away but... note that the Euclidean division $$a^3-1=(a+1)(a^2-a+1)-2$$ shows that $\gcd(a^3-1,a+1)=\gcd(2,a+1)\in\{1,2\}$, and I am sure that you can see why the gcd is $1$ when $a$ is even (as in your question) and $2$ when $a$ is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,
since $a$ is even,
$\gcd(a + 1, a - 1) = 1$.

Since
$a^3-1
=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)
$,
$\gcd(a^3-1, a+1)
=\gcd(a^2+a+1, a+1)
=\gcd(a^2, a+1)
=1
$.

Comment: thank you so much! both you and @lulu have helped me a great deal!

Comment: It's nice to upvote or accept.

Comment: sorry, first time on the site. just did both!

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but in my haste i overlooked the final conclusion. 
how does one ascertain that gcd(a^2, a+1) = 1?

Comment: Because $gcd(a, a+1) = 1$.

Comment: thank you so much, Mr. Cohen!